# JDB -- How to get a list of methods before running the program?

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I'm learning JDB and running into a bit of a paradox. After starting JDB (with "jdb ClassName") most tutorials will tell me to type

> > methods ClassName

to see a list of available methods so that I can set my breakpoints. If I do that, JDB replies

> Command 'methods' is not valid until the VM is started with the 'run' command

Of course, if I say "run" before setting any breakpoints, it runs straight through; not very helpful. The only thing I can conclude is that jdb expects you to set your breakpoints blind, but this seems like such a gross oversight, I'm holding out that I'm simply missing a command.

Many thanks!!
Joyce

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are *two* ways to create a debugging session (see the [jdb documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdb.html)).

1. *Attaching* - We load the program into a virtual machine, it pauses listening on a port (e.g. 8000). Then in another terminal session, we load jdb and attach it to the JVM session by specifying the port.

   - in one termial session:`java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,
     address=8000,server=y,suspend=y ClassName`
   - in a second terminal session: `jdb -attach 8000`
2. *Launching* - Load jdb and tell it the name of the class to load.

   - in a single terminal session: `jdb ClassName`

If you are *attaching*, then you don't need to use the `run` command.
However, if you are *launching*, then you **do** need to use the `run` command (the virtual machine hasn't been started yet).

---

This behaviour can be inferred from `man jdb`:

> **run** -
>   After  starting `jdb`, and setting any necessary breakpoints, use this
>   command to start the execution of the  debugged  application. *This
>   command is available only when `jdb` launches the debugged application
>   (as opposed to attaching to an existing VM)*.

This is why you have the error message. You  *launched* the debugger but didn't use the `run command`.
Some tutorials may incorrectly tell you to *launch* jdb, but forget to tell you to execute the `run` command.

---

Below shows how to get the list of methods (assuming you have `main` method in a class called `ClassName`).

1. *Attaching*:
   `jdb -attach 8000`
   `main[1] stop in ClassName.main`
   `main[1] cont`
   `main[1] methods ClassName`
2. *Launching*:
   `jdb ClassName`
   `> stop in ClassName.main`
   `> run`
   `main[1] methods ClassName`

**Hint**: look at jdb's command prompt. Sometimes it's `>`, sometimes it's like `main[1]`. If it's `>`, then the VM hasn't started and commands such as `classes`, `methods` won't work until you have used the `run` command. If the prompt is `main[1]`, the VM has been started and desired commands will work.

---

> The only thing I can conclude is that jdb expects you to set your breakpoints blind

It is difficult to set breakboints using the debugger alone. You need to be looking at your source code elsewhere. You will likely know the name of at least one method to break at and thus set an initial breakpoint using 
`stop in ClassName.MethodName`. If you don't know where to break, you can always set a breakpoint on your main method using `stop in ClassName.Main`. 
Remember that while the debugger is running, you can set more breakpoints. Also, you may find, the `list` command useful - it shows the source code corresponding to the current breakpoint hit.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same question.

So after running:

```
jdb -classpath build -sourcepath src MyClass
```

the text I entered is in bold below in the `jdb` session:

```
> stop in MyClass.main
Deferring breakpoint MyClass.main.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run
run MyClass
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint MyClass.main

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", MyClass.main(), line=798 bci=0
798         MyClass singleton = new MyClass();

main[1] list
797     public static void main(String[] args) {
798 =>      MyClass singleton = new MyClass();
799
```

Comment: ...and if you're using Spring which hijacks the main() method, you were helpless. Hashtag don't use Spring!

Answer (score 0):

If it's your own program you're debugging, I'd think you'd know the class names!

If it's a program for which you don't have the source code, then to run it you must know the class name containing `main()`. If it's in a jar started with `java -jar`, the name of that class is in the manifest inside the jar.

But in fact you're running `jdb ClassName`, so you *know* you'll be running method `ClassName.main()`. Right?

If it's a servlet in a web service, the class of the servlet is in `web.xml`.

So in any of those cases you should at least be able to get the very first method. Once there, you can find the rest.

Comment: ugh this is so unhelpful. I might be debugging some open source code that does not belong to me.